# Should you expose third party library symbols through a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, software-design

I'm wondering about a situation where you are statically linking a third party library to your DLL library. If your DLL includes some functions implemented in headers (like if you have template functions), and these functions call your third party library (think general purpose, like `absl::StrAppend()`), then you need to either

1. export the third party library symbols from your DLL via a .def module or something, or
2. ask your client to statically link to the third party library.

Both solutions seem like problems. The first one could create duplicate symbols if your client happens to be linking against the same third party library for their own code. The second means your library isn't self-contained, and might impose versioning requirements on the third-party library that your client could be using at another version. Is there a clean solution here?

Comment: Header only libraries in a DLL contradict the reason they exist. If you have a header only library, what's the point of the DLL?

Comment: When the DLL is built, all third-party (static) library references will be resolved into that module, just as when building an EXE. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I'm talking about a DLL where some functions need to be implemented in headers, not a header-only library. e.g. you might have a couple of template functions you need to expose.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, third party references will be resolved. But you need to provide header files with your DLL, and if the header files for the DLL used by the client contain third party references, those need to be resolved on the client-side.

Comment: Then I refer you to the first comment by Michael. Wrap those templates inside your own?

Comment: @AdrianMole Not sure exactly what you mean. I suppose you could wrap all references to third party libraries with your own code, but that seems pretty messy.

Comment: Sorry. I meant wrapping the calls. It's trivial to replace calls like `foo(bar)` with `MyFoo(bar)` and export `MyFoo`. If you have to do that more than a few times, then maybe a DLL isn't what you actually need.

Comment: It depends on your compiler, but I know most of compilers support that "expose only what you specified". Eg: like `.def` for visual studio and I believe they could "hide" all the symbols that you don't want to expose.

Comment: Per your statement in question, I think #1 is what you want to do for exporting the dll, but I'm not sure why `.def` would leave the symbol you don't want to expose being exported. Maybe you want to elaborate on it. It would be easier to help if you provide a [mre].